# Node.js Outlook Add-In Event Handler for Item Send Event?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm new in creating **Outlook Add-In** and I'm using **Node.js** on my project, I dont know whats wrong with my code using **Event Handler for Item Send Event**, but its not working at all, can anyone help me with my project, please....

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>470141da-c6df-4f45-b860-867cf2c96f79</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  
  <ProviderName>QuickBase</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="QuickBase"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="This Add-In let you send email data to QuickBase Documents Table."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-128.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:3000</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <!-- On Send requires VersionOverridesV1_1 -->
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>

          <!-- Message Read -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ActionButton">
                  <Label resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="ActionButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>action</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control> -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

          <!-- Message Compose -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgComposeCmdGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeInsertGist">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Title"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

          <!-- Message ItemSend Event -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
            <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="onItemSend" />
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="QuickBase"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Use Add-In"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Title" DefaultValue="Use Add-In"/>
        <!-- <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Insert default gist"/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Title" DefaultValue="Insert default gist"/> -->
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Send email information to QuickBase and create a record of the email."/>
        <!-- <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Inserts the content of the gist you mark as default into the current message."/> -->
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

**taskpane.js**

```
Office.onReady((info) => {
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Outlook) {
    document.getElementById("sideload-msg").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("app-body").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("run").onclick = run;
  }

  Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemSend, function (eventArgs) {
    eventArgs.completed({ allowEvent: true }); // allow the event to continue
    var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    var subject = item.subject;
    item.saveAsync(function (asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        var url = asyncResult.value.getRestUrl();
        console.log("Subject: " + subject);
        console.log("URL: " + url);
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to save item.");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

the **onItemSend** function doesn't work after pressing the **Send** button on composing a new email from Outlook, I tried adding a API Request to the function but it doesn't work, whats seems to be the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest you specified the function file in the following way:

```
 <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
```

where the string value is defined below:

```
<bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
```

So, you need to define the callback in the `commands.js` file. That is where the Office runtime will be looking for the callback.

Read more about the `ItemSend` event in the [On-send feature for Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows) article.

Comment: The updated my add-in now when I run the add-in on the windows app its says that `The add-in is  preventing this message from being sent, the callback function is unreachable.` on web app its says `We're sorry, we couldn't access QuickBase. Make sure you have a network connection. If the problem continues, please try again later.` and `The add-in QuickBase has prevented this item from being sent.`

Comment: I updated my post above for the xml and js file, I hope you can help me out.